# JMeter Performance Discrepancy Between Old and New APIs

Tags: jmeter

I'm facing a peculiar issue while conducting performance testing using JMeter, and I could use some guidance in troubleshooting this problem.

**Background:**
We have an API where we recently introduced a new API that clusters several calls into a single call. The old API required multiple POST and GET requests to achieve the same result, while the new API simplifies this by making a single POST request that internally calls the old API. Surprisingly, during performance testing, we observed that the new API is significantly faster than the old API, even though it relies on the same underlying calls.

**Issue:**
One of the GET requests within the old API is taking much longer than expected during JMeter load testing, and this is causing a performance discrepancy between the old and new APIs. We are trying to understand why this particular GET request is taking longer than expected.

Check caching mechanisms in the new API
Check response data from both APIs
Compare request from both APIS

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to provide a comprehensive answer without knowing your "new API" implementation details, it might be the case it runs calls to the "old API" [in parallel](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and then aggregates the responses, it might be the case it keeps [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) open instead of establishing a connection to each service separately, it might be the case it [caches](https://www.gomomento.com/blog/6-common-caching-design-patterns-to-execute-your-caching-strategy) popular responses and doesn't make an actual request if the data is relatively "fresh".

So you need to ensure that network footprint of JMeter test is the same as the "new API" produces and set up JMeter's [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler accordingly.

With regards to a single service taking longer than expected - use a profiler tool to inspect what's going on under the hood, [identify the bottleneck](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/bottleneck-testing) and fix it.